# Java find greatest integer in array list

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, integer, compare

Im trying to run a for loop that prints each users score in an array list.
I don't know how to output who has the greatest/highest score however. Can someone please help me?

```
for (int i = 0; i < playersList.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + ", "
                + playersList.get(i).getName() + " Score: " + playersList.get(i).getTotalScore());
        playersList.get(i).getFrameScores();


        System.out.println("**************");

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

First, find the max score using one iteration over your elements in list. Then, use another iteration to seek whose  players have the max score and print them.

Here's a pseudocode for the above algorithm:

```
int maxScore <- Integer.MIN_VALUE
for each player in playerList
    if maxScore < player->score then
        maxScore <- player->score
    end if
end for
//now you have the max score
for each player in playerList
    if player-> score == maxScore then
        show player info
    end if
end for
```

Comment: @user2864740 what do you mean by JOBOL, Java + Cobol or something similar?

Comment: Yeah :-) However, I do like this answer (as much as I will allow myself), because it also addresses the case where multiple people can have the same max score.

Comment: @user2864740 well, there's no need to get too complex for easy tasks :). Besides, since it is pseudocode, the implementation may use a `Comparator` if needed for the score comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double maxScore = playersList.get(0).getTotalScore();
ArrayList<String> maxNames = new ArrayList();
maxNames.add(playersList.get(0).getName());
for (int i = 1; i < playersList.size(); i++) {
    if(playersList.get(i).getTotalScore() > maxScore) {
        maxScore = playersList.get(i).getTotalScore();
        maxNames.clear();
    }
    if(playersList.get(i).getTotalScore() >= maxScore ) {
        maxNames.add(playersList.get(i).getName());
    }
}
StringBuilder names = "";
for(int i=0; i<maxNames.size(); i++) {
    names.append(maxNames.get(i));
    if(i != maxNames.size() - 1) {
        names.append(", ");
    }
}
System.out.println("The player" + (maxNames.size() > 1 ? "s" : "") + " with the highest score " + (maxNames.size() > 1 ? "are" : "is") + " " + names + ", with a score of " + maxScore + ".");
```

Comment: What if there are several players with maximum score?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It will output the first one to get the highest score. I will fix that.

Comment: Fixed. It will now output _all_ players with the maximum score.

Answer (score -1):

Assign the first value as max and compare every coming values. If coming value is large set it as max and compare it with remaining.

For ex

```
var max =0;

for(i=o;i<5;i++) {
  if(i==0){ var max = a[i]; }

   if(max < a[i]) {
      max= a[i];
   }
}

alert(max);
```

Comment: Isn't this `JavaScript`?

Comment: Yes this is javascript, but you can adopt same logic for java to achieve the outcome.