# How to find highest and lowest value on substrings?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
String s_prices = "19; 16; 20; 01; 16; 1.3; 1.6; 50; 2.0; 17";

// Convert to List of strings:
// ["19", "16", "20", "01", "16", "1.3", "1.6", "50", "2.0", "17"]
        List<String> prices = Arrays.asList(s_prices.split("; "));

// Convert to List of 3-element lists of strings (possibly fewer for last one):
// [["19", "16", "20"], ["01", "16", "1.3"], ["1.6","50", "2.0"], ["17"]]
        List<List<String>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < prices.size(); i += 3) {
            partitions.add(prices.subList(i, Math.min(i + 3, prices.size())));
        }

// Convert each partition List to a comma-delimited string
// ["13, 16, 20", "01, 16, 1.3", "1.6, 50, 2.0", "17"]
        List<String> substrings = partitions.stream().map(p -> String.join(", ", p)).collect(Collectors.toList());


// Output each list element on a new line to view the results
        System.out.println(String.join("\n", substrings));
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.pprices);
        tv.setText(String.join("\n", substrings ));
```

and I want to find the highest and the lowest price on every substring and show results on *TextView* as follows

```
19, 16, 20  High: 20, Low: 16
01, 16, 1.3  High: 16, Low: 01
1.6, 50, 2.0  High: 50, Low: 1.6
17  High: 17, Low: 17
```

Comment: What exactly did you want for the first one?  You should replace the ellipses in that example to make it clearer, e.g. `19, 16, 20  High: 20, Low: 16`.

Comment: yes like this your example, that is what I want for the first one as you have given on your eg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) and [`Collections.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection,java.util.Comparator)) methods return the largest/smallest element in a list.  These can be used while mapping the `partitions` list with [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)) to return the results in the format you're looking for:

```java
Comparator<String> numberValueComparator = Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new);
List<String> groupedValue = partitions.stream()
        .map(p -> String.format("%s  High: %s, Low: %s",
                String.join(", ", p),
                Collections.max(p, numberValueComparator),
                Collections.min(p, numberValueComparator)))
        .toList();

System.out.println(String.join("\n", groupedValue));
```

Output:

```
19, 16, 20  High: 20, Low: 16
01, 16, 1.3  High: 16, Low: 01
1.6, 50, 2.0  High: 50, Low: 1.6
17  High: 17, Low: 17
```

Note that it's important to compare the numeric value of the string, rather than the string itself.  For instance, using the natural order of strings, "1001" < "17".  This is why this is using a `Comparator` that first converts the number to a `BigDecimal` using the [`BigDecimal(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) constructor, and then compares those values.

Comment: Thank you, how about first and last price in a substring

Comment: @Exsent `partition.get(0)` and `partition.get(partition.size() - 1)`.

Comment: where is the code do I add this?